# Gatling: For long term should we put one REST API in one simulation?

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling

We have decided to use Gatling as performance testing tool. But we are not able to figure how should we keep our simulations. Since we have around 25 API's as of now. So do I need to create 25 simulation for each API. This question is more on maintenance of code.

Comment: A simulation should simulate the users' behaviour.
You can refer to the [documentation](https://gatling.io/docs/current/general/concepts).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to achieve. Do you want to only test each API in isolation? Or do you want to simulation real traffic that would be distributed over the different API calls with different weights?

I recommend extracting the calls to dedicated classes like it's being done in [the tutorials](https://gatling.io/docs/current/advanced_tutorial/) and have multiple Simulations depending on your needs.